# How to create a big data frame in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, tfidf, sparse

I have a sparse matrix, $X$, created by TfidfVectorizer and its size is $(500000, 200000)$. I want to convert $X$ to a data frame but I'm always getting a memory error.

I tried

`pd.DataFrame(X.toarray(), columns=tokens)`

and

`pd.read_csv(X.toarray().astype("float32"), columns=tokens, chunksize=...)`.

And it seems that when I convert $X$ to a numpy array using  `X.toarray()`, I get an error.

Can someone tell me what is an easy solution for this? Is there anyway I can create a sparse dataframe from $X$ without memory error?

I have been running my codes on Google Colab Pro and I think it provides me less than 100 GB Ram.

Comment: I think the real answer here is "don't do that". Look into one of the distributed computing frameworks instead of trying to do everything on one machine.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pandas.Dataframe.sparse.from_spmatrix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix.html#pandas.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix).  It will create a Dataframe populated by `pd.arrays.SparseArray` from a scipy sparse matrix.

Pandas used to have explicit sparse dataframes, but in more modern versions there is no such concept.  Only normal pd.Dataframe populated by sparse data.

Comment: The sparse data frame is created but the problem is how can I work with that? When I feed it into neural networks, again it gives a memory error.

Comment: @Moonlight You asked how to create a sparse data frame. If your actual issue was "I want to run a huge dataset through some neural nets via Pandas", then that's what you should have asked in your question.

Answer (score 2):

I have had to deal with huge data frames as you mention, in mi case the problem was "solved" by storing the data frame as pickle `pd.to_pickle()` and not as csv.

The memory usage reduced by 60%

I also heard recently about a format named [feather](https://robotwealth.com/feather-r-python-data-frame/)

For reference:

https://towardsdatascience.com/the-best-format-to-save-pandas-data-414dca023e0d

[image]

Comment: This one seems to need a path to store a previously created data frame. I haven’t created a data frame yet

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `max_df` and `min_df` or `max_features` for tfidfvectorizer apart from sparse array.